# motion.conf missing webcam

Tags: streaming-video, webcam, motion, osmc

Last night I tried to get motion running on my pi for a live stream from a webcam plugged into it. I read through multiple tutorials, and they all said the same things for the most part. The problem is that they all say to change a few things in the webcam section of `motion.conf`, but that section just isn't there for me. I tried to add it myself but it gave me an error something like 'unrecognized command' (I'm not near my pi for the moment).

I'm running OSMC on a Pi 2. The conf file contains what appears to be everything else it should, definitely everything else the tutorials called for. I ran both

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptget upgrade
```

and it still doesn't work.

It did tell me that it started the daemon, and I tried to see the stream on the page. Once I was able to get a still shot, but other than that just a 'missing' image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motion changed some variable names in recent versions. To view the stream in a web-browser (http://192.168.0.*:8081) you need to set the 'stream_localhost' to off. This enables other devices on your network to view the stream (not just localhost). All of the streaming settings have new names and can be found about 3/4 of the way down in a section called 'Live Stream Server'.

To test if the stream is working though, launch the browser on the Pi and go to http://localhost:8081 - if the default settings are working this will return your stream. If not, the 'Live Stream Server' settings aren't the problem...